# In installing phonegap get NPM ERR Fetch Failed

Tags: node.js, cordova, npm

First i am install node.js in my 64bit windows8 laptop and then i am install phonegap and then cordova using

```
npm install -g phonegap and npm install -g cordova.
```

I am set all the required path in PATH variable in enviroment variable.

All thing is running well but now suddenly cordova command is not working.

Give error like

```
Cordova command is not recognized internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Now i am uninstall all thing and trying to install again now i get error like

http://prntscr.com/4ueq9k

http://prntscr.com/4uehll

I am trying all solution from stackoverflow but cannot get success.

Please please help me. :'(

Comment: can you try to login as administrator and install cordova/phonegap?

Comment: @frank Yes i am trying also